# Passing parameters to AppleScript function

Tags: excel, applescript

I'm trying automate a lengthy Microsoft Excel workflow

From the docs:

> **open workbook** v : Opens a workbook.

> **open workbook**

> **workbook file name** text : The name of the file containing the workbook to be opened.

> [**update links** do not update links/‌update external links only/‌update remote links only/‌update remote and external links] : Specifies the way links in the file are updated. If this argument is omitted, the user is prompted to specify how links will be updated.

> ...

I can successfully

```
tell Application "Microsoft Excel"
    open workbook workbook file name v
end tell
```

Now, according to the docs, I would like to pass the parameter `update links` giving `update remote and external links` but I'm totally clueless about the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The correcy syntax is

`open workbook workbook file name v update links update remote and external links`

unfortunately for some reason external links are not loaded

Furthermore Excel keeping asking permssion to open each file each time.

Bah...

Comment: Are you running the script from Script Editor? Or as a standalone app? And is the one you're using set up in System Preferences 'security & privacy'?